# Why npm start command is not working on my window os?

Tags: java, reactjs, command

I don't know Why this command: npm start is not working

[image: Error Details]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a `package.json` file within a project.

Try use `npm init` [Documentation - npm init](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file)

Comment: after running the command npm init it is asking package I have given package name as package.json after it is asking from me versions? what should I enter over there?

Comment: Are you trying to run an existing project? if yes, make sure you are in the correct directory when running `npm start`, that is, the one which already contains the `package.json` file. If you're trying to create a react project from scratch, you can refer to this [guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/).

Comment: @Babookumarheerani the version doesn't matter. It up to you. The only name is necessary

Comment: @BartSmagacz sir I have included package.json instead of that npm start command is not running?

Comment: @Babookumarheerani I'm sorry but I can't understand you.
After creating a new project (npm init) you should have a package.json file. After that, you can add commands such as npm start. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @BartSmagacz respected sir, I want to create the new project I have I have run the command npx create-react-app after that when I run the npm start command I am facing the following two errors.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-26T08_51_00_724Z-debug.log

Comment: @Babookumarheerani So please follow `create-react-app` installation [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html). Or paste full error because the last line of it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have you `NVM` present in the `Environment Variables`. Else, it won't work1

Comment: I don't know about it

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_OWfA4dHtY - Check this video! This would help!